# How to make Request.Content from .NET 4.8 to work in .Net Core? Or Request.Body from .Net Core to .NET 4.8?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httprequest

I have this code that runs locally on .NET 4.8 for development. Once it will be pushed to GitHub, it will be built using .net core. (plan is to migrate to .NET core eventually, so set up like this).

Locally Request.Content will build in .NET 4.8 and works fine. But if I pushed it, it will have an error. If I use Request.Body from .NET core, it will not build on local but will build on repo. If I do this, all Devs local set up will have the error which is not acceptable.

So I was looking for a code (no setup/environment changes) which is an interoperable for both. Basically what I am looking for is to read the whole request string from the HTTP Request.

Hopefully somebody can shed some light.

Comment: Are you pushing the assembly? If so, I'd say run .NET Core locally. If you are pushing the source, then I'd say use conditional compilation. I suppose the third option is to use reflection, see which is available at runtime, and use that one. Wrap that (with cache, so you don't do reflection every time) into an extension method.

Comment: Technically, developers are still running .NET 4.8, I could not run .NET Core as if i do commit my code, all other Devs will have error on theirs.

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
using system.Net;
```

Then a web client:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
```

Then you  can download a webpage as a string.

```
string download = webClient.DownloadString("https://google.com");
```

From that you can probably extract the body.

This will work if you can get the data as a webpage however if it's just a request then it probably won't. Also I don't know if this will work for whichever .NET version thingy you are using.
Sorry if this response isn't particularly helpful.